# Metro App reading HTML formatted string

Tags: c#, html, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a metro app and want to bind a `<TextBlock>` element to a string which contains some HTML formatting elements.  I seem to remember there being a converter for this kind of thing pre-WinRT, but I can't find any reference to this in the WinRT namespace.

Here's an example of the string:

```
This is<br>a string with some formatting<br>elements<img src="http://image-url">
```

At the minute I'm just binding this to a TextBlock and getting a poorly formatted piece of markup.  Without writing a mini-converter myself, is there a way to deal with this for WinRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WebView and WebView has method WebView.NavigateToString(HTMLContent). Hope this might help.